# UDPClient receives the data from some default port address though i have specified the port address while initiating the object

Tags: c#, network-programming, udpclient

```
public void Listener(int portNo)
        {
            listener = new UdpClient(portNo);
            serverEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, portNo);
            while (true)
            {
                byte[] data = listener.Receive(ref serverEP);
                RaiseDataReceived(new ReceivedDataArgs()
                {
                    Ipaddress = serverEP.Address,
                    Port = serverEP.Port,
                    ReceivedBytes = data
                });
            }
        }
```

> ```
> public class ReceivedDataArgs : EventArgs
> {
>     public IPAddress Ipaddress { get; set; }
>     public int Port { get; set; }
>     public byte[] ReceivedBytes;
> }
> ```

Here, in this method i am passing the port address where i want to listens the data. But, unfortunately it is printing some random port address. 
Seeking a help regarding this.

Comment: You're worried that `serverEP.Port` doesn't contain the same value as `portNo`? That's expected. You're *listening* on `portNo`, but someone *sending* you data can *send* it from any port they want to.

Comment: Hi @carton7 Thanks for your swift response. I would like to listen to specific port which i have mentioned. Can you help me in that case?

Comment: That is what your code does, already. You are doing the right thing. I think you are confused by the fact that `serverEP.Port` "is printing some random port address", which is why I told you that this is expected

Comment: Agreed, Suppose I am sending data to this updclient with port address 124. Does this port address will be getting print or some other port.

Comment: I don't follow your question. Every UDP packet has a **source port** and a **destination port**. You are listening on port `portNo`. Every packet sent **to** you will have a **destination port** of `portNo`. Every packet sent **from** you will have a **source port** of `portNo`